# How to get cell font color

Tags: java, apache-poi

I'm preparing code for validating Excel sheet content. Some fields under some conditions are filled with font with red color, so I need to have this information for validation.

I tried with `cell.getCellStyle().getFontIndex()`. I see that for fields filled with black, it returns 1 value and for fields filled by red it returns 3, but then when I tried `workbook.getFontAt(1).getColor()`, I receive 0 in both cases.

Comment: XSSFCellStyle has getFont() that returns an XSSFFont instance and that has getColor() and getXSSFColor()

Answer (score 2):

`Font.getColor` returns an index of an indexed color. That works using the old binary Excel file format `*.xls` (`HSSF`) as there all colors only could get from a color palette. But the new Office Open XML file format `*.xlsx` (`XSSF`) also provides colors stored directly as `RGB` and not coming from a color palette. Those colors will not have an index then. So `Font.getColor` returns `0` then.

The most compatible way I have found is to get a `org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Color` from the `Font` instead of an index. Unfortunately this only is possible using different ways in `HSSF` and `XSSF`. So we need to differentiate `HSSFFont` and `XSSFFont`. Then we can get either `HSSFColor` or `XSSFColor`.

Complete example which shows this for both `HSSF` and `XSSF`:

```
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;

import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.*;
import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.*;
import org.apache.poi.hssf.util.HSSFColor;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.*;

public class ExcelGetFontColor {
    
 //method to get current font from cell
 //gets only font of whole cell not font of possible rich text content
 private static Font getFont(Cell cell) {
  Workbook workbook = cell.getSheet().getWorkbook();
  CellStyle style = cell.getCellStyle();
  return workbook.getFontAt(style.getFontIndex());
 }

 private static Color getFontColor(Font font, Workbook workbook) {
  Color color = null;
  if (font instanceof XSSFFont) {
   XSSFFont xssfFont = (XSSFFont) font;
   color = xssfFont.getXSSFColor();
  } else if (font instanceof HSSFFont) {
   HSSFFont hssfFont = (HSSFFont) font;
   color = hssfFont.getHSSFColor((HSSFWorkbook)workbook);
  }
  return color;
 }
 
 private static String getHexString(Color color) {
  String result = null;
  if (color instanceof XSSFColor) {
   byte[] rgb = ((XSSFColor)color).getRGB();
   result = toHexString(rgb); 
  } else if (color instanceof HSSFColor) {
   short[] triplet = ((HSSFColor)color).getTriplet();
   result = toHexString(triplet);
  }
  return result;
 }

 private static String toHexString(Object arrayOfNumbers) {
  String hex = "";
  if (arrayOfNumbers instanceof byte[]) {
   for (byte b : (byte[])arrayOfNumbers) {
    hex += String.format("%02X", b);
   }
  } else if (arrayOfNumbers instanceof short[]){
   for (short s : (short[])arrayOfNumbers) {
    hex += String.format("%02X", s);
   }      
  }
  return hex;
 }
    
 public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

  String inFilePath = "./ExcelExampleIn.xlsx"; String outFilePath = "./ExcelExampleOut.xlsx";
  //String inFilePath = "./ExcelExampleIn.xls"; String outFilePath = "./ExcelExampleOut.xls";
  
  try (Workbook workbook = WorkbookFactory.create(new FileInputStream(inFilePath));
       FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(outFilePath ) ) {

   for (Sheet sheet : workbook) {
    for (Row row : sheet) {
     for (Cell cell : row) {
      System.out.print("Cell: " + cell.getAddress());
      Font font = getFont(cell);
      //System.out.print(", Font:" + font);
      System.out.print(", Font:" + font.getFontName());
      System.out.print(", FontColorIndex: " + font.getColor());
      Color color = getFontColor(font, workbook);    
      //System.out.print(", FontColor: " + color);
      System.out.println(", FontColorHEX: " + getHexString(color));
     }
    }
   }
   
   workbook.write(out);
  }
 }
}
```